# How to use gdalwarp to reproject a raster without changing band labels?

Tags: qgis, raster, gdal, gdalwarp

## Procedure

I used QGIS to reproject a raster data. QGIS does this via `gdalwarp` like so:

```bsh
gdalwarp -overwrite -t_srs EPSG:4326 -of GTiff /path/to/input.tif /path/to/output.tif
```

## Comparison of input and output files

**input.tif**
[image]
**output.tif**
[image]

Is it possible to use `gdalwarp` to reproject a raster without changing band labels? If so, how?

Comment: I don't know, but you can just copy and paste the style from your original raster (right click on the layer).

Comment: Right, raster styles are saved into external style file (.qml) that contains entries like `<colorPalette>
        <paletteEntry label="0" color="#32c82c" value="0" alpha="255"/>
        <paletteEntry label="test" color="#59d1c3" value="1" alpha="255"/>`. Plain GeoTIFF is not aware of labels.